# unexpected labels change on React-Admin's version update

Tags: react-admin

I update my react-admin version from `2.5.2` to `2.8.0` and all react-admin's native buttons (edit/create etc) and resources labels have changed.

There are some cases I was able to fix it, for example changing every `EditButton` to have `label='edit'` prop, but how can I change it in other components? like `<Resource>` or `<List>` or the create button rendered in `<Create>`? has anyone encountered this and knows to explain why this happened?

please see attached [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLaKK.png) for more details, the unexpected labels are marked with red.

*** EDIT ***
After further investigating this issue I came across [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3007) issue on their repo, many users had this issue when upgrading react-admin.

I can confirom this was fixed by removing `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and running `npm install`.

Comment: Your translation doesn't work: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html

Comment: Thank you for this lead, I further investigated this issue and came across this on react-admin's repo (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3007), 
apparently many users had this problem when upgrading a version.
I can confirm this was fixed by removing package-lock.json, node_modules and running npm install.